# Find data between dates using BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a bigquery table where a column is name timestamp and it contains a string time value(Fri Jun 03 16:04:53 UTC 2022)

I would like to create a bigQuery query to return value between 2 dates (08/07/2023 and 08/08/2023)

How can I do this in BigQuery

here is part of my query

** SELECT type,count(type) FROM `event`
group by type**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use [`PARSE_TIMESTAMP`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions#parse_timestamp) to convert a string into a `TIMESTAMP` value.

Example:

```sql
SELECT DATE(PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%a %b %d %k:%M:%S UTC %Y','Fri Jun 03 16:04:53 UTC 2022'))

--  2022-06-03
```

The select query would look something like:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE
DATE(PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%a %b %d %k:%M:%S UTC %Y', timestamp)) BETWEEN '2022-08-07' AND '2022-08-08'
```